# Base url em slded css data-lazyload

Tags: css, json, codeigniter

*I am trying to put the base URL inside the image to load but it can help me Base URL in data-lazyload*

```
<li data-transition="fade" data-slotamount="7" data-masterspeed="500" data-saveperformance="on" data-title="Intro Slide">
   <!-- MAIN IMAGE -->
   <img src="<?=base_url("template/view/img/slides_bg/dummy.png")?>" alt="slidebg1" data-lazyload="<?=base_url("template/view/img/slides_bg/slide_1.jpg")?>" data-bgposition="center top" data-bgfit="cover" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat">
   <!-- LAYER NR. 1 -->
   <div class="tp-caption white_heavy_40 customin customout text-center text-uppercase" data-x="center" data-y="center" data-hoffset="0" data-voffset="-20" data-customin="x:0;y:0;z:0;rotationX:90;rotationY:0;rotationZ:0;scaleX:1;scaleY:1;skewX:0;skewY:0;opacity:0;transformPerspective:200;transformOrigin:50% 0%;" data-customout="x:0;y:0;z:0;rotationX:0;rotationY:0;rotationZ:0;scaleX:0.75;scaleY:0.75;skewX:0;skewY:0;opacity:0;transformPerspective:600;transformOrigin:50% 50%;" data-speed="1000" data-start="1700" data-easing="Back.easeInOut" data-endspeed="300" style="z-index: 5;max-width: auto; max-height: auto; white-space: nowrap;">text
   </div>
   <!-- LAYER NR. 2 -->
   <div class="tp-caption customin tp-resizeme rs-parallaxlevel-0 text-center" data-x="center" data-y="center" data-hoffset="0" data-voffset="15" data-customin="x:0;y:0;z:0;rotationX:0;rotationY:0;rotationZ:0;scaleX:0;scaleY:0;skewX:0;skewY:0;opacity:0;transformPerspective:600;transformOrigin:50% 50%;" data-speed="500" data-start="2600" data-easing="Power3.easeInOut" data-splitin="none" data-splitout="none" data-elementdelay="0.05" data-endelementdelay="0.1" style="z-index: 9; max-width: auto; max-height: auto; white-space: nowrap;">
      <div style="color:#ffffff; font-size:16px; text-transform:uppercase">
         text
      </div>
   </div>
   <!-- LAYER NR. 3 -->
   <div class="tp-caption customin tp-resizeme rs-parallaxlevel-0" data-x="center" data-y="center" data-hoffset="0" data-voffset="70" data-customin="x:0;y:0;z:0;rotationX:0;rotationY:0;rotationZ:0;scaleX:0;scaleY:0;skewX:0;skewY:0;opacity:0;transformPerspective:600;transformOrigin:50% 50%;" data-speed="500" data-start="2900" data-easing="Power3.easeInOut" data-splitin="none" data-splitout="none" data-elementdelay="0.1" data-endelementdelay="0.1" data-linktoslide="next" style="z-index: 12;"><a href='rooms_list.html' class="button_intro">text</a> <a href='all_activities.html' class=" button_intro outline">text</a>
   </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to load the url helper in autoload.php

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

and also set base_url in your config.php file

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://host/appname';
```